# xsd - How to avoid mixed="true" what is the alternative?

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

I Need to avoid mixed="true" because my Microsoft SSIS grouses if I use mixed="true" in my *.XSD-File. I get the following error message:

> "...The XML source adapter does not support the model of mixed content on complex types"

My XML-File:

```
  <MappingProject name="anyString1">
     <MappingSpecification name="anyString2">
        <MappingTargetTable>TEXT_BLOCK1</MappingTargetTable>
        <MappingSourceTables>
           <Table>TEXT_BLOCK2</Table>
           <Table>TEXT_BLOCK3</Table>
        </MappingSourceTables>
        <Description>
           <DescriptionText>Some Text...  </DescriptionText>
           <Condition type="filter"> -</Condition>
        </Description>
     </MappingSpecification>
  </MappingProject>
```

My XSD-File:

```
<!-- <MappingProject> -->
<xs:element name="MappingProject">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MappingSpecification" type="MappingSpecificationType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<!-- MappingSpecification -->
<xs:complexType name="MappingSpecificationType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MappingTargetTable" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="MappingSourceTables" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="Description" type="DescriptionType" minOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- Description -->
<xs:complexType name="DescriptionType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="DescriptionText"/>
        <xs:element name="Condition" type="ConditionType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- Condition-->
<xs:complexType name="ConditionType" mixed="true">
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

This Part: `xs:complexType name="ConditionType" mixed="true"` is needed because else I get any error message like:

> "Element 'Condition' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is 
>    element-only."

What now? I can't use `mixed="true"` because MS SSIS don't likes it but otherwise I get an error. Can you help me please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the element respectively type should have no child elements but at least one attribute then you should define it as

```
<xs:complexType name="ConditionType">
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="string">
              <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            </extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: But one more question, if this is possible... How can I expand this? with maybe one more <sequence> and <element> in the upper <complexType>?

Comment: The sample XML you have shown for that element is `<Condition type="filter"> -</Condition>` which does not have any child elements. You have other types  like `MappingSpecificationType` where you know how to define a complex type with attributes and child elements. So if you want e.g. `<Condition type="filter"><Expression>foo</Expression><Expression>bar</Expression></Condition>` then I think you know how to do it. If you really need to mix text contents with element contents then you need ` mixed="true"` but it sounds as if your target system does not support that.

Comment: In general http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/ is a good read on the different possibilities the schema language offers.